# Error parsing XML document with multiple tags

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, sax

My XML looks like this :

```
<uc-export clientvers="8.00"> <JOBP AllowExternal="1" client="5000" name="DEV_1234" system="DEV">
 </JOBP></uc-export>
<uc-export clientvers="8.00"> <JOBP AllowExternal="1" client="5000" name="DEV_435" system="DEV">
 </JOBP></uc-export>
<uc-export clientvers="10.0.8+build.472"> <JOBS_UNIX AttrType="UNIX" client="5000" name="TEST_JOB123" system="DEV"><node content="1" id="VALUE" name="Variables" parent="" type="VALUE">
```

I need to extract the  tag from the xml, whether it is a JOBS_UNIX or JOBP object

I am using DocumentBuilderFatory

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
File file = new File(path);
Document document = db.parse(file);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
list = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
Element element = (Element) list.item(1);
jobProps = element.getAttributeNode("name").getValue();
```

I am able to parse documents it it is having 1 element, but it is not working multiple tags

Comment: Basically, that's not a valid XML document - XML documents can't have multiple root elements. You could *make* it a valid document by just adding `<root>` at the start and `</root>` at the end...

Comment: or parsing each line separately...

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a well-formed external general parsed entity (often referred to for short as an XML fragment), but it is not a well-formed document entity, so you can't parse it in the usual way. The simplest way to parse it is to prepend `<dummy>` and append `</dummy>` -- but that only works if you're confident there isn't going to be an XML declaration or BOM on the file. A safer (and perhaps more efficient) way is to construct an XML document that refers to this one using an entity reference, and then parse the referencing document. It would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE dummy [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<dummy>&e;</dummy>
```